# Component inside custom generated HTML in Angular

Tags: angular

I have an Angular component in which I generate some `div`s and `svg`s, using plain Javascript (`document.createElement('div')`, `this.elementRef.nativeElement.appendChild(div)`, ...) Is it possible to have another Angular component inside those generated `div`s?

I have read about `ComponentFactoryResolver` but I'm not very sure if it would apply here. I guess the generated elements would have to be compiled by the Angular compiler, but I'm not sure if this can be done.

Comment: You read about factory resolver but have you even try to implement anything?

Comment: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45390942/2545680)

Comment: thi [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/dynamic) might help in dynamic component

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat I didn't see any place to pass in the DOM element, so that's why I asked it here

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com The link helped, thanks