# How dynamically load Angular component from jQuery-inserted selector

Tags: jquery, angular

We have a hybrid legacy application consisting of use-cases implemented as Spring MVC, jsp and jQuery. Each use-case is a SPA built from “components” made up of jsp/jQuery. Each component is loaded dynamically using innerHTML + AJAX.

We want to start rewriting this application one component at a time, and the preferable route is to create Angular components at the innermost level, and then aggregate them outwards until each use case is a homogenous Angular application.

Are there a "clean" way to use Angular components in the jQuery-loaded part of the DOM, for example by dynamically bootstrap angular components when the legacy jQuery inserts selectors in the DOM “outside” the angular root application, similar to [Dynamically add components to the DOM](https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/dynamically-add-components-to-the-dom-with-angular-71b0cb535286) with Angular except that's from within angular. This implies: from jQuery, tell angular that there is a new selector to bootstrap.

Comment: what is jQuery-inserted selector ?

Comment: Of course it is possible

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com my way of describing jQuery('#divid').append('<app-angular></app-angular>')

Comment: @yurzui Great! Please tell me how!

Comment: @JonasAndersson, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45390942/2545680)

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com Great link! That answer shows how to bootstrap the component which takes me halfway!  But unless I'm missing something it doesn't tell how to trigger Angular from jQuery after the jQuery...append()?

Answer (score 0):

What we ended up doing (so far) was bootstrapping angular-components at startup, but keep them hidden.
After the AJAX-call has updated the DOM, we use jQuery to move each component to the updated part of the DOM.

Work's great and keeps the angular code clean and unaware of jQuery, so that it remains unchanged when all jQuery is replaced.

To pass parameters to angular we use the angular router with hash strategy so that jQuery can pass parameters by changing the url. (Will migrate to push-based when the application is plain Angular.)