# Can't set routerLink in popUP Leaflet Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, leaflet

In my project I try to set the links to popUps, like this

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.ParseService.getJ().subscribe(data => {
    this.myData = JSON.parse(data);

    //set markers and popUps
    for(let i = 0; i < this.myData.length; i++) {
      let lat =+((this.myData[i])['lat']);
      let lng =+((this.myData[i])['lng']);
      this.id = (this.myData[i])['code'];
      let popUp = (this.myData[i])['displayName'] + '<br/><a [routerLink]=["/buildings", this.id] routerLinkActive="active">room</a>';
      let markerLocation = L.latLng(lat, lng);
      let marker =  new L.Marker(markerLocation, {icon: customIcon});
      map.addLayer(marker);
      marker.bindPopup(popUp);
    }
  });
```

So, the problem is with the second line of this code

```
 let popUp = (this.myData[i])['displayName'] + 
'<br/><a [routerLink]=["/buildings", this.id] routerLinkActive="active">room</a>';
```

If I replace it it with

```
let popUp = (this.myData[i])['displayName'] + '<br/><a href="http://www.google.com">Raumplan</a>';
```

it works.

What is the problem, why routerLink doesn't work?..

Comment: Why are you making a string of HTML, rather than creating a child component? I don't think the bindings will be handled the same at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can one render Angular 2 Components inside DOM elements from third party libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45390312/can-one-render-angular-2-components-inside-dom-elements-from-third-party-librari)

Comment: @jonrsharpe I guess I don't need child component, after the click on "room" should the new page appear. Is there some workarounds?